# Values of successive wait durations for unsuccessful Android pattern tries

Tags: security, pattern-lock

On my smartphone running Android 9, the pattern lock seems to work the following way:

1. The user is allowed 5 attempts to draw a pattern.
2. If all patterns in (1) above are incorrect, the user has to wait time t1 before they are allowed to make other 5 attempts.
3. After time t1, if all the next 3 attempts are incorrect, the user has to wait time t2 before they are allowed to make other 5 attempts.
4. After time t2, if all the next 3 attempts are incorrect, the user has to wait time t3 before they are allowed to make other 5 attempts.
5. And so on...

From my experiments, I know for a fact that the values of t1, t2, and t3 are 1 minute, 10 minutes, and 30 minutes respectively. My question is, is there a manual that lists the other next values for t4, t5, t6, ..., tn? Or, perhaps, is there a way to calculate them?

Comment: there is a formula on [gist.github.com](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/58592651#58592651)

Comment: @alecxs, If I'm interpreting the formula correctly, after 20 incorrect patterns, the user will need to wait for 30 seconds, correct? But on my device, when I test this, I'm notified that I need to wait an hour. What's more, for another device running Android 4.4.2, the wait duration is fixed at 30 seconds, regardless of the count of incorrect patterns entered (I can provide screenshot evidence if you so require it). What gives? Is the wait period manufacturer-defined or Android-defined?

Comment: android 7+ gatekeeper, wait for 30 sec after 5, 10 attempts. increase timeout after 30+ attempts up to 1 day after 140+ attempts. formula *= 30 \* (2^((x - 30)/10)) seconds*